# What are the angels doing in the blessing on light?

Tags: blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, malach-angel

In the Yotzer Ohr prayer, we praise God for creating the light. It then moves on to an interlude about the ministering angels. What does that have to do with the light?

Comment: Is the prayer about light or is it about the new day, in which we discuss the creation of light?

Comment: @DonielF it seems to be a blessing on the light. that's why it is said at dawn when the light comes

Comment: Or maybe it’s said on the day, which is why we say it at dawn, the beginning of the new day. Consider Berachos 11b: “Says Rava, to mention the attribute of day during the night, and the attribute of night during the day. The attribute of the night during the day is good, as we say, ‘Who fashions light and creates dark.’ But where do we find the attribute of the day during the night? Says Abaye, ‘Who rolls light in front of dark and dark in front of light.’” (Con’t)

Comment: (Con’t) The Gemara doesn’t say “light” and “dark,” but rather “day” and “night.” Seemingly then the Gemara understands the morning blessing of Yotzer Or and the evening blessing of Hama’ariv Aravim as referring to the day and night, respectively, with the light and dark being symptoms, rather than vice versa.

Comment: @DonielF  because day is when the light of the sun comes

Comment: Why are you so insistent that it must be the blessing on light, rather than a blessing on the day?

Comment: @DonielF because it's called yotzer ohr. not yotzer yom

Comment: So how do you explain the Gemara?

Comment: @DonielF see my previous comment. i also heard tapes by rav miller where he says the blessing on light is the longest blessing and how pleasurable light is, etc.

Comment: So day is when the light comes out. Great. It’s still imprecise according to you - it should still say light and dark, not day and night.

Answer (score -2):

**IIRC Rabbi Avigdor Miller זצ"ל used to explain "we discuss how the angels get all excited about the new day, etc."**

Answer by: Danny Schoemann

Comment: What if he doesn't remember correctly?

Comment: question was what does the angels have to do with the creation of light

Comment: There's a reason Danny posted this as a comment rather than an answer.